# How to draw button into table once using dataTable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

*So I am trying to add a button two each row in the table. 
I was able to accomplished this by doing the code below, but the button keeps generating every time i go to the next page and come back to it. It adds one button to the table every time I go between pages. I dont understand why this happening. Can someone please help me out. Thank you in advance.*

$('#displayTable').on('draw.dt', function () {

```
    $('.dataTable > thead > tr').append('<th style="width: 163px"></th>');
    //adding button to table.
    $('.dataTable > tbody > tr').append('<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary topic-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_to_topic">Add to Topic</a></td>');
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You may use TableTools extension for DataTables to add custom buttons to table header.

In the override options:

```
"aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "text",
                "sButtonText": " ",
                "fnInit": function ( nButton, oConfig ) {
                    $(nButton).attr("title", "Delete selected items");
                    $(nButton).removeClass("DTTT_button").addClass("btn btn-small");
                    $(nButton).append('<i class="icon-trash"></i> <i class="icon-white icon-exclamation-sign"></i>');
                },
                "fnClick": function( nButton, oConfig, oFlash ) {
                    if (!$(nButton).attr('disabled')) {
                        // code to run on click
                        deleteSelectedItems();
                    }
                }
            }
   ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response i am going to try this and get back with you.

Comment: Hey Kursad, so tried what you suggested and i couldnt get it to work, but i was able to get it to work by doing this
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#displayTable').on('draw.dt', function () {
  if($('.topic_add').length == 0) {
    $('.dataTable > thead > tr').append('<th style="width: 163px"></th>');
  }
 $('.dataTable > tbody > tr').not(':has(".topic_add")').append('<td class="topic_add"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary topic-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_to_topic">Add to Topic</a></td>');
});

</script>

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future looking for an answer, this is what I did

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#displayTable').on('preInit.dt', function () {
        //adding column to table.
        $('.dataTable > thead > tr').append('<th>header</th>');
    });
    $('#displayTable').on('draw.dt', function () {
        //adding button to column.
        $('.dataTable > tbody > tr').append('<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary topic-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_to_topic">Add to Topic</a></td>');
    });
</script>
```